# How can I get the value of an account created in mocha test?

Tags: solidity, truffle, mocha

I am new to ethereum and am using truffle and mocha for development. I am writing an app that is sending ethereum to a contract. The ether stored in the contract is then used later.

I have a function that creates a ticket by calling to a seperate contract: TicketAccount (which holds all the tickets in an account).

```
function createTicket(bytes32 _name, uint _cost) public payable returns(address ticket) {
    var setBalance = _cost * 2;
    var ticketAddress = accounts[msg.sender].createTicket.value(setBalance)(_name, _cost);
    return ticketAddress;
  }
```

I am referring to the docs [here](http://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/develop/control-structures.html?highlight=.value(#external-function-calls)
This is the function it is calling to. A user must have registered an account to be considered an owner.

```
function createTicket(bytes32 _name, uint _cost) public payable isOwner() returns (address ticketTransaction) {
    // ... code here
  }
```

I am writing a mocha test where service is my original contract where the createTicket can be called from.

```
it("should create ticket", function() {

    var newTicket = service.createTicket.value(20)("Ticket Name", 20);
    return newTicket.then(function(newTicket) {
      assert.isOk(newTicket);
    });
  });
```

This is the error that the test is giving

```
TypeError: service.createTicket.value is not a function
```

UPDATE: I have also tried this method to no avail. This gives me the dreaded invalid opcode

```
var newTicket = service.createTicket.sendTransaction("Ticket Name", 20, {from: accountOne, value: 40});
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the format your looking for is:

```
service.createTicket(arg1, arg2, {value: 30, from: accounts[3]}, function(err, result) {
   console.log(result)
}
```

At least, that works for me.